# Change css property dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pseudo-element

I'm trying to change the background color of a class dynamically, the color that I have to use comes from an API. I'm using a pseudo-element because what I want to achieve is like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jg1Lea5c/)

```
  <div class="despesas_interna">


                    <a ng-class="{'status ': style(despesa.categoria_cor)}">

                        {{despesa.data | amDateFormat:"DD/MM/YYYY"}}
                        <span>{{despesa.categoria_nome}}
                        <i class="ion-ios-arrow-right despesas_arrow"></i>
                        </span>

                        <p>

                            {{despesa.valor | moneyFormatBR}}
                            <span> </span></p>
                    </a>

                </div>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.style = function(value) {
            return { "background-color": value };
        }
```

CSS:

```
.despesas_interna {

    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.despesas_interna a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 7px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

}

.despesas_interna a.status:before {

    background-color: #87c424;

}
```

Comment: Seems like ng-style is better suited for this

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-style` instead of `ng-class`. You have two ways to use it:

```
<div ng-style="style(value)">
```

and

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color': value}">
```

Comment: still not getting what I want, I need to change the color of background of ".despesas_interna a.status:before" dynamically